# AWS EC2 image list empty

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I created an AMI using the AWS management console. Now I wanted to use AWS SDK for .NET using Visual Studio 2010 to launch an EC2 instance using the AMI image I created. I am able to get the security group and key pair I created but when I try to get image list using DescribeImagesRequest and Response with filter as owner-id, I get an empty list.
Please help as to why I can not see any of the images that I created.
I have used the same region for the security group, key pair and the image

```
        var ownerId = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        DescribeImagesRequest imagesRequest = new DescribeImagesRequest();
        Filter ownerFilter = new Filter();
        ownerFilter.Name = "owner-id";
        List<String> filterValues = new List<string>();
        filterValues.Add(ownerId);
        ownerFilter.Values = filterValues;
        List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>();
        filters.Add(ownerFilter);
        imagesRequest.Filters = filters;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Image request created");
        DescribeImagesResponse imagesResponse = ec2Client.DescribeImages(imagesRequest);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Image response received");

        List<Amazon.EC2.Model.Image> images = imagesResponse.Images;
        System.Console.WriteLine("The total number of images are : " + images.Count);
```

The images.Count is empty and its not getting any images though I can see the images listed on the AWS management console.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I added it in my question

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but using the "owner-alias" filter. 
I wanted to use "self" to get all my AMIs. Instead of using the filter I'm using the "Owners" property which is working with the "self" alias.

```
DescribeImagesRequest imagesRequest = new DescribeImagesRequest();
imagesRequest.Owners.Add("self");
DescribeImagesResponse imagesResponse = ec2Client.DescribeImages(imagesRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nuno, the same issue with the iOS SDK. Setting the ownerIds property to self did the trick.